# remove line from jsonobject

Tags: java, android, json, opencart

I have a JSON object like this, 
it is used for getting the shipping method from opencart API.
I asked about "how to fill array from this jsonobject in android" ago in this post [how to fill array from json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756164/how-to-fill-array-from-json-object),
but I did not receive any answer.

Now I want to remove some lines that marked with symbols shown as "====>"

```
{
  "shipping_methodsx": [
    {
      "title": "حمل و نقل با هزینه ثابت",
      "quote": [
        {
  ====>   "flat": {
            "code": "flat.flat",
            "title": "هزینه حمل و نقل",
            "cost": "10000",
            "tax_class_id": "0",
            "text": "10,000 تومان"
  ====>   }
        }
      ],
      "sort_order": "1",
      "error": false
    },
    {
      "title": "حمل و نقل رایگان",
      "quote": [
        {
  ====>   "free": {
            "code": "free.free",
            "title": "حمل و نقل رایگان",
            "cost": 0,
            "tax_class_id": 0,
            "text": "0 تومان"
  ====>   }
        }
      ],
      "sort_order": "3",
      "error": false
    },
    {
      "title": "پیک فروشگاه",
      "quote": [
        {
  ====>   "pickup": {
            "code": "pickup.pickup",
            "title": "ارسال توسط پیک فروشگاه",
            "cost": 0,
            "tax_class_id": 0,
            "text": "0 تومان"
   ====>  }
        }
      ],
      "sort_order": "2",
      "error": false
    }
  ]
}
```

and make it useable in my android app like this:

```
{
  "shipping_methodsx": [
    {
      "title": "حمل و نقل با هزینه ثابت",
      "quote": [
        {
            "code": "flat.flat",
            "title": "هزینه حمل و نقل",
            "cost": "10000",
            "tax_class_id": "0",
            "text": "10,000 تومان"
        }
      ],
      "sort_order": "1",
      "error": false
    },
    {
      "title": "حمل و نقل رایگان",
      "quote": [
        {
            "code": "free.free",
            "title": "حمل و نقل رایگان",
            "cost": 0,
            "tax_class_id": 0,
            "text": "0 تومان"
        }
      ],
      "sort_order": "3",
      "error": false
    },
    {
      "title": "پیک فروشگاه",
      "quote": [
        {
            "code": "pickup.pickup",
            "title": "ارسال توسط پیک فروشگاه",
            "cost": 0,
            "tax_class_id": 0,
            "text": "0 تومان"
        }
      ],
      "sort_order": "2",
      "error": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone helps me to make this?

Comment: This is server response problem and must be fixed by server side.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think OP just wanted to highlight the rows to remove with `====>` and didn't mean that arrows actually appear in the output.

Comment: That said, I don't see why the original JSON would not be "useable" as it is.

Comment: exactly, just take whatever you want from the json and ignore the rest?!

Comment: lines marked by me for better Understanding. original json object have not "====>" . i put this symbol before lines that to show i want remove that lines from json object . changing server response , will affect other functions.i only want remove Specific lines. Forgive me. English is not my native language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the gson to covert the Json string to a json Model, then change the json model's content to fit you need. At last, convert the json model to json string back. Here the sample code:

```
public class Model {
    List<Model1> shipping_methodsx;

    class Model1 {
        String title;
        String sort_order;
        boolean error;

        List<Model2> quote;
        List<Model3> quote1;
    }

    class Model2 {
        @SerializedName(value = "flat", alternate = {"free", "pickup"})
        Model3 key;
    }

    class Model3 {
        String code;
        String title;
        String cost;
        String tax_class_id;
        String text;
    }
}

public static String removeSomeJson(String json) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Model ret = gson.fromJson(json, Model.class);

    for(Model.Model1 model1: ret.shipping_methodsx){
        model1.quote1 = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Model.Model2 model2 : model1.quote) {
            model1.quote1.add(model2.key);
        }
        model1.quote = null;
    }

    return gson.toJson(ret);
}
```

Comment: thank you very very much http://stackoverflow.com/users/4382249/moon . your anwser is perfect.it worked like charm